# How do i turn this into a for loop statement?

Tags: java

Thanks in advance! Not homework or whatever I am just playing with someone else's code.

```
String s = "";
System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
s = input.next();      
System.out.println(s.length() - s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u|", "").length());
```

Comment: Read the introduction to loops in your favourite book.

Comment: You didn't say what you want to do ^^

Answer (score 2):

I would use a while loop that way you can enter as many sentences as you want and determine when to exit based on a word entered by the user. My example uses "exit" to exit the program.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";

    while(!s.equals("exit"))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        s = input.nextLine();
        if(!s.equals("exit"))
            System.out.println(s.length() - s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u|", "").length());

    }
```

Output of Program

```
Enter a sentence: hello world
3
Enter a sentence: the cat jumped over the moon
9
Enter a sentence: exit
```

Comment: Thx i tried that (Im sticking with for loops for now) but for some reason my output is: Enter number of loops: 3
Enter a sentence: 0
Enter a sentence:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what you do is you put a for loop around the entire statement. I'll show you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String s = "";
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    s = input.next();   

    System.out.println(s.length() - s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u|", "").length());
}
```

This code will run the inside of the loop 10 times. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, brilliant! I cant believe i forgot that just putting a number was a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use charAt to read a given character from a string.  You would use a for loop to go through the indices.  So, it would read like

```
for ( int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++ )
{
char c = s.charAt(x);
//Change c as you want
System.out.print(c);
}
```